# Vagrant SSH session closes when logging in to VPN

Tags: shell, vagrant, vpn

I have established a SSH session to my Vagrant development machine with `vagrant ssh`. When I login to or logout from Pulse Secure VPN, the SSH session terminates with the following error:

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.`

What may cause the termination of the session?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your network adapter changes when you initiate or terminate a VPN session so the ssh connection opened with the guest VM has to close for the time the adapter are recycled.